# How to launch VScode in a particular Conda environment on a Mac

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, oh-my-zsh

I have Jupyter v2022.9.1202862440, Jupyter keymaps v1.0.0, Jupyter Notebook Renderer v1.0.10, Jupyter Slideshow v0.1.5, Extensions installed in VScode and am trying to run a .ipynb code block directly in VScode on a MBP. I use conda to manage my python environments and run oh-my-zsh with powerlevel10k.

I would like to learn a workflow to get VScode to automagically launch in a particular environment (only the shell in vscode launches the right environment with #2 below) and then be able to execute the Jupyter cells within a .ipynb with that same environment. This is what I've tried so far that isn't working:

1. Opening iterm2, running a `conda activate <the-name-of-environment-i-want>` followed by a `cd <to-code-dir>` and finally `code .`
2. adding a line in settings.json "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/py310" for a 3.10x version created with conda
3. Running a cell in .ipynb with

```py
from platform import python_version
print(python_version()) # prints out a 3.9x
```

still outputs the wrong interpreter.

I've read so much documentation it is running out my ears. I think there is a last saved configuration that it may be defaulting to, but I'm not sure. A simple one line explanation here might be best, if possible. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-Kernels-and-the-Jupyter-Extension#python-extension-and-ipykernel if someone else agrees I may close this with an answer